# how does getline read only up to a newline without seeking?

Tags: c, linux, getline

I'm imagining reading *byte by byte* would be very inefficient, but reading in bulks would almost always read more than needed, requiring to store the rest of the read input in a global context for all subsequent read operations to find. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prototype is:

```
ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
```

So it's clearly using `FILE`, which is already buffered. So reading character-by-character is not inefficient at all.

Comment: So it's `FILE` that is keeping the context. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That is what *buffered io* is for. Long story short, the C library reads a full buffer the size of which is implementation dependant but is rather large, and then the `getline` function looks for the first newline in that memory buffer, leaving the pointer positioned for next access.